Measurement of s11 of differential output antenna transmitter
Normally, when we look at the s11 parameters from the feed point of a single-ended antenna, we can easily see the s11 reflection coefficient, yes.

Now, the question I am wondering is this: I have a differential output transmitter. First, it goes to the balun (it converts the differential input to single-ended). Then, the match circuit and a monopole helical antenna. In this case, I want to observe the reflection coefficient in order to adjust the bandwidth and impedance in the same way. In this case, where should I place the ports? Can I create a mathematical equation between the ports and observe the general s11 performance? Or, will connecting the 2nd port to gnd in the balanced part of the balun give me the correct result?



I do not get your question about where to place the ports!? You already have some ports placed in the schematic. Please explain what you would like to achieve. Is it a question about measurement or simulation?

Hi , I think question is clear. I am asking how I should place the port to observe return loss on the differential line.

The answer to your question highly depends on the situation, especially on the balanced side.
If both conductors on the balanced side do have a high degree of isolation towards GND, then you can e.g. connect GND to one balanced pin of the B0310 and measure the reflection/S11 with a port connected to the other pin. In this case you need to set the port impedance to 100 ohms.
If both conductors on the balanced side have high isolation towards each other and at the same time they have 50 ohms towards GND (conductors are symmetrical to GND, i.e. they are both referenced to the GND plane but are seperated from each other), then you can do the same measurement as above, but this time with a 50 ohms port.
In other cases, you must assume a three conductor system on the balanced side, which makes things complex.
From a practical point of view, in case you want to build and measure this circuit, I can give you the following advice:

You need to make sure that your copper traces on your PCB have 50 ohms impedance on the unbalanced side and 100 ohms differential or each 50 ohms towards GND on the balanced side.

Do not populate B0310, connect a VNA to L110 (usually with a UFL type  connector on a unpopulated PCB footprint) and measure and tune the antenna impedance to 50 ohms with the L-C-L network.

Populate the B0310.


Voila, you're done.
